Function for reading of the JPEG DCT coefficients by python
import jpeglib
im = jpeglib.read_dct("golet.jpeg")
Luminance = im.Y
print(Luminance)
I need to print luminance i get this error: TypeError: DCTJPEG.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
note: my image in the same folder of this code
I try to get or reading the  DCT of jpeg image
